# Cin and method statement

Tags: c++, cin

I've seen this written when accepting input (myDetails is a struct):

```
cout << "Enter your weight: ";
(cin >> myDetails.weight).get();
```

my problem is that I don't understand it. How can the whole statement become like an object and have a method called get()?. I can understand that cin has a method called get(), what are the brackets around cin creating?

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Comment: ok, thanks for letting me know. Was just adding some personal touch to the message.

Answer (score 6):

The operator>> here will just return a reference to std::cin, so it's that that you're calling get() on. The brackets are necessary so that you don't end up trying to call get() on myDetails.weight.

More generally, stream extraction operators usually have signatures like this:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, thing& rhs);
```

They then return their first argument so as to support chaining. This, in combination with the fact that >> is left-associative, allows you to write e.g.

```
std::cin >> a >> b;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
operator>>(operator>>(std::cin, a), b);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can the whole statement become like an object and have a method called get()?

Because it's not just a statement; it's an expression. The overloaded `operator>>` for `istream` returns `istream&`, meaning that the expression `cin >> x`, whether used on its own or as part of a wider *full-expression*, will evaluate to an `istream&` (specifically, a reference to `cin` itself).

That's how chaining works: `cin >> x >> y` is the same as `(cin >> x) >> y`, so you can see that this only works when `(cin >> x)` evaluates to `cin`; your example is just the same, with the distinction that you're invoking member `.get()` rather than member `operator>>`.